# QGIS Layer creation failed for shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

QGIS v3.4.4

New project and trying to add a shapefile (line) layer w/ manual data entry.

1. > Layer>Create layer>New Shapefile layer
2. Fill out the form w/ a file name, geometry type and I added a Date field to the list w/ the default id field
3. Click OK
4. "Layer creation failed. Please check message log for further information"
5. Message log has time stamp, "WARNING:  (blank)"

What am I missing?

Comment: just tested in QGIS v2.18.28 and the same process works fine

Comment: Do you have permission to save the files in the folder you have specified

Comment: I do.  @kartoza-geek